# How to determine that app become active by tapping on local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

1. An app is running on iPhone and user tap the home button once and app will enter background.
2. after 2 or 3 seconds local notification arrives and user tap on local notification.
3. app will again enter in foreground and become active and `didReceiveLocalNotification` will be called.

How to determine that app become active by tapping on local notification not the app icon.

Comment: This looks like a possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061897/ios-push-notification-how-to-detect-if-the-user-tapped-on-notification-when-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to detect what's your App's status when `UILocalNotification` fired and if
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`
 is called, this makes sure that local notification is received.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        // Application was in the background when notification was delivered.
    } else {

    }
}
```