# iOS 10 UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate not called. push notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Tearing my hair out tying to get push notifications to work in iOS10. Current setup:

in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    print("DID REQUEST THE NOTIFICATION")
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
            print("DID SET DELEGATE")
        }
```

In `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`:

```
print("DID REGISTER FOR A REMOTE NOTIFICATION AND THE TOKEN IS \(deviceToken.base64EncodedString())"           
let request = UpdatePushNotificationSubscription_Request(deviceToken: deviceToken)
updatePushNotificationSubscriptionWorker.updateSubscription(request)
```

I have checked the token is uploaded to the backend correctly and it does indeed match.

I have also implemented:

```
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("GOT A NOTIFICATION")

    }


    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        //This is for the user tapping on the notification
        print("GOT A NOTIFICATION")
    }
```

I have set the entitlements for all targets and enabled push:

[image]

Now when I try to send a message from the backend the device just receives nothing. Delegates are not being called. Have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Push is working for iOS9 and android devices. Any pointers to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: this is not really an answer, as I am still having the same problem as you. Try checking out if your device token is parsed correctly, because for me, as of ios10, it was not. I did fix it however, but I still don't have my delegates called

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: did anyone have a solution for this? I am also experiencing the same issue since iOS 10 - now on iOS 10.1.1

Comment: Did u resolve your issue . Even i am facing

Comment: I think the problem is that you didn't call `completionHandler` in your `userNotificationCenter` methods. Just add it and test.

Answer (score 113):

This answer pertains to iOS 10+, using the `UserNotifications` framework.

You need a class to conform to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol. It doesn't matter if you create a new class just for this, or add it on to your `AppDelegate` class. I'd recommend creating a dedicated class though. For the purposes of this answer, let's assume you create a `UserNotificationController` class for it.

The class can have the following methods:

`optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)`

`optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`

Then in your `AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method, you need to set the `delegate` on the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` object to an instance of your `UserNotificationController` class. You'll probably want to use a shared instance.

Request authorization from the user to enable notifications using the `UNUserNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)` method, and in the `completionHandler`, check the `granted` value. If `true`, register for remote notifications by calling `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`.

Now, when the app receives a push notification, there are several different situations that can happen. I'll try and list the most common cases here.

**Local Notifications:**

If the app is in the foreground, the app will call `UserNotificationController .userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`.

If the app is in the background (running or not), nothing is called until the user taps the notification, at that point, the app will open and call `UserNotificationController .userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.

**Remote Notifications:**

The content of the payload will affect what happens. There are three cases for the payload, a) just the normal `alert`, `badge`, and `sound` options b) including the `content-available` option (set to `1` or `true`) c) including the `mutable-content` option (set to `1` or `true`). Plus there's technically d) where you have both `content-available` and `mutable-content`, but that just triggers both cases.

*For a) just `alert`, `sound`, `badge` info:*

This works the same as a local notification.

*For b) `content-available` == true:*

If the app is in the foreground, `UserNotificationController .userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` is called.

If the app is in the background, (running or not), `AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` is called, not one of the methods in your `UserNotificationController` class.

*For c) `mutable-content` == true:*

If you've added a `UNNotificationServiceExtension` to your application, it will handle the notification and can modify the content. This happens regardless of the state of your main application. If the (optionally modified) notification is tapped by the user it is then handled like a local notification above.

Without a `UNNotificationServiceExtension`, the notification is treated like a normal remote notification above.

**Additional Notes:**

When using `mutable-content`, you must include `alert` info in the payload, or the system will treat it as immutable and not call into your `UNNotificationServiceExtension`. Your modified notification must still include `alert` info, or the original notification payload will be used. Sadly there's no way to prevent the notification from appearing to the user.

When using `content-available`, if the user force-quit the app the last time they used it, the system will not relaunch the app or call `AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`. Though it will still display any alert, play the sound, and update the badge as indicated in the payload.

Comment: @DaveWood https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357155/ios-stream-audio-when-local-notification-fire

Comment: @DaveWood Does this work with CloudKit push notification, or is CloudKit push notification a totally different framework?

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum It should work. CloudKit uses the same UserNotifications framework.

Comment: can you please share UserNotificationController is it viewcontroller or nsobject

Comment: @KamrujjamanJoy `UserNotificationController` is the class you create to manage your notifications. It could be anything (though I recommend not using a ViewController). You'll want an object that lives for the duration of your app's lifetime. A dedicated `NSObject` subclass is your best bet.

Answer (score 29):

Try making your AppDelegate class implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol instead of a separate class implementing the protocol.

I had a separate class for the delegate and it didn't work. This is how my code looked when I got it working:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application 

    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self //DID NOT WORK WHEN self WAS MyOtherDelegateClass()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
            if granted {
                // update application settings
            }
    }

    return true
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)->()) {
    withCompletionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler: @escaping ()->()) {
    withCompletionHandler()
}

// and so forth for your other AppDelegate stuff
```

Comment: Since the UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate is weak, you have to keep it alive yourself. that's why AppDelegate is a good candidate here. You can also build a class juste for that and keep it alive in you AppDelegate or anywhere else :)

Comment: @PO Bengtsson and @zarghol Thanks! You made me understand why my `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods weren't being called. I have a separate class to handle notifications. How can I manage to keep this class alive in order to make sure the delegate methods will be called?

Comment: You can do this by simply use a singleton of your class, or just keep a strong reference of your class somewhere (appdelegate, your current view controller...)

Answer (score 22):

I struggled with this for a full day. Sometimes I was getting notifications, sometimes not, but I could never get the `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:completionHandler:)` callback to to triggered.

It turned out there were two problems. The first I'm still a little confused by: my target deployment version was set to 11.0 but my project was set to 10.0. Changing the project to 11.0 was the first step. I don't fully understand this but maybe there is some difference in notification handling between 10.0 and 11.0?

The second part was the notification center delegate. I noticed Apple's [note in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate):-

> **Important**
>
> You must assign your delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter
>   object before your app finishes launching. For example, in an iOS app,
>   you must assign it in the
>   application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method of your app
>   delegate. Assigning a delegate after these methods are called might
>   cause you to miss incoming notifications.

I had been setting in a separate "notification manager" class, which is where the callbacks were also located (as delegate protocol implementations). I had instantiated this as an instance var in my app delegate, assuming this would be created early and not cause a problem.

I messed around with the instantiation etc for a while but only when I set the delegate in my `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method and implemented the delegate callbacks in the app delegate did I manage to fix it.

So my code became, basically:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // You MUST do this HERE and nowhere else!
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    // other stuff

    return true
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // These delegate methods MUST live in App Delegate and nowhere else!

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        if let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
        }
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
The placement of this one made it talk to me from the app. Thanks.

Comment: It was really helpfull for me, thanks for posting this! Had the same problem, used a notification manager class.

Comment: bro thank you so much, about a year ago this answer saved me and today it saved me again; no one tells you about the ```UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self```

Comment: Thanks bro. saved the day

Comment: These methods are not being called when app is in background, what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not set `UNNotificationCategory`'s `intentIdentifiers`, if code like this:

```
UNNotificationCategory* expiredCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"TIMER_EXPIRED"
                                               actions:@[snoozeAction, stopAction]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                               options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
```

it will not called UNUserNotificationCenter's delegate methods, so you must set intentIdentifiers like this :

```
UNNotificationCategory* expiredCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"TIMER_EXPIRED"
                                               actions:@[snoozeAction, stopAction]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[@"a",@"b"]
                                               options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. Please call `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` inside `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        //register UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in case of app comes from background to forground.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As well as making sure you use the `AppDelegate` for the `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate, and setting the delegate in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method on launch, make sure you also remember to import `UserNotifications` and `UserNotificationsUI`.

Comment: Lee, why do you actually need the UI one, UserNotificationsUI ??

Comment: Honestly? I can't remember now.

Comment: gotchya Lee !   for anyone googling here, I'm pretty sure you DO NOT need it: normally works fine without!  You must import `UserNotifications`