# Authenticate a user upon clicking apple watch notification

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-watch

I have a watch app which gets notifications. I wanted to get the user authenticated upon clicking on the notification. 
  So that only registered users can take action once inside the app. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35475659/42446